# Hypothesis Testing with Limited Precision Real Numbers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Hypothesis testing in all 11 of the math stat textbooks on my desk deals with either real numbers that have infinite precision or discrete numbers (i.e., integers). I have been unable to locate a discussion of hypothesis testing with real numbers that have limited precision, such as the results from a chemical analysis that are rounded to two significant digits from the floating point precision of 16 significant digits. I am interested in learning how the rounding process impacts the errors rates of a given test and whether one should test before rounding or after. Can anyone suggest some sources that might address this? Thanks.

Comment: Just so you are aware, this form of limited precision conforms to the textbook definition of discrete.  That does not make your question any less relevant, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following paper addresses this topic directly:

*The effect of rounding on the power level of certain normal test statistics*

A. R. Tricker

Journal of Applied Statistics (Impact Factor: 0.45). 01/1990; 17:219-228. DOI: 10.1080/757582833

Comment: Thanks. Tricker appears to have published a number of papers on this topic.